# iBeacon: RSSI detection frequency differs in background from foreground mode. why?

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon, rssi, region-ranging

During my investigation concerning the RSSI detection reliability for iBeacons, I discovered that the RSSI frequency differs extremely between foreground and background mode.

My setting:
Two beacons setup in a venue (vending machine) broadcasting the same UUID and Major, but different Minors => Region defined using UUID and Major.

Use case 1:
Approaching the venue with my smart phone in my pocket (running app in background). Dwelling for 15 seconds in front of venue (distance 1.5 meter).

Use case 2:
Approaching the venue with my smart phone in my hand, running the app in foreground. Dwelling for 15 seconds in front of venue (distance 1.5 meter).

Ranging logs for use case 1:

```
[2016-03-07 16:22:31] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:31] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:32] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:32] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:33] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:33] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:34] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:34] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:50] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:50] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551527 
[2016-03-07 16:22:51] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:51] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:51] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:51] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:52] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:52] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:52] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:52] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:53] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:53] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:53] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:53] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:54] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:54] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:54] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:54] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:55] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:55] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:55] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:55] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:56] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:56] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:56] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:56] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:57] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:57] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:57] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:57] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:58] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:58] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:58] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:58] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:59] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:59] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:22:59] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:22:59] Maj.: 16  0
```

Ranging log for use case 2:

```
[2016-03-07 16:51:04] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:04] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:04] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:04] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551521 
[2016-03-07 16:51:05] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:05] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:05] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:05] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551521 
[2016-03-07 16:51:05] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:05] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:05] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:05] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551524 
[2016-03-07 16:51:05] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:05] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:05] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:05] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551524 
[2016-03-07 16:51:06] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:06] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551518 
[2016-03-07 16:51:06] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:06] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551528 
[2016-03-07 16:51:07] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:07] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551520 
[2016-03-07 16:51:07] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:07] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551533 
[2016-03-07 16:51:08] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:08] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551525 
[2016-03-07 16:51:08] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:08] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551538 
[2016-03-07 16:51:09] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:09] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551525 
[2016-03-07 16:51:09] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:09] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551538 
[2016-03-07 16:51:10] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:10] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551521 
[2016-03-07 16:51:10] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:10] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551536 
[2016-03-07 16:51:11] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:11] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551522 
[2016-03-07 16:51:11] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:11] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551535 
[2016-03-07 16:51:12] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:12] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551523 
[2016-03-07 16:51:12] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:12] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551536 
[2016-03-07 16:51:13] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:13] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551522 
[2016-03-07 16:51:13] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:13] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551534 
[2016-03-07 16:51:14] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:14] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551522 
[2016-03-07 16:51:14] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:14] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551534 
[2016-03-07 16:51:15] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:15] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551522 
[2016-03-07 16:51:15] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:15] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551535 
[2016-03-07 16:51:16] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:16] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551522 
[2016-03-07 16:51:16] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:16] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551537 
[2016-03-07 16:51:17] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:17] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551522 
[2016-03-07 16:51:17] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:17] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551535 
[2016-03-07 16:51:18] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:18] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551521 
[2016-03-07 16:51:18] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:18] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551535 
[2016-03-07 16:51:19] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:19] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551521 
[2016-03-07 16:51:19] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:19] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551535 
[2016-03-07 16:51:20] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:20] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551521 
[2016-03-07 16:51:20] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:20] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551534 
[2016-03-07 16:51:21] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:21] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551522 
[2016-03-07 16:51:21] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:21] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551534 
[2016-03-07 16:51:22] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:22] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551519 
[2016-03-07 16:51:22] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:22] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551533 
[2016-03-07 16:51:23] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:23] Maj.: 30  18446744073709551520 
[2016-03-07 16:51:23] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:23] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551531 
[2016-03-07 16:51:24] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:24] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:24] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:24] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551518 
[2016-03-07 16:51:25] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:25] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:25] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:25] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551518 
[2016-03-07 16:51:26] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:26] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:26] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:26] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551517 
[2016-03-07 16:51:27] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:27] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:27] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:27] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:28] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:28] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:28] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:28] Maj.: 16  18446744073709551520 
[2016-03-07 16:51:29] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:29] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:29] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:29] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:30] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:30] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:30] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:30] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:31] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:31] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:31] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:31] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:32] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:32] Maj.: 30  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:32] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:32] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:33] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:33] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:34] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:34] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:35] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:35] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:36] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:36] Maj.: 16  0 
[2016-03-07 16:51:37] lumen.INFO: Range Beacon [2016-03-07 16:51:37] Maj.: 16  0
```

Does anyone know why the detection frequency of the RSSI value does differ that much between the two use cases? Is ranging in the background that much worse?

Thx.

Comment: What is the numeric value in the log in the rightmost column?  Is it some calculated value of RSSI?  What does it mean when it is 0?

Comment: Yes. The right most value is the RSSI.

Comment: The RSSI should be a value between 0 and -100, so I'm not sure why the log shows such large numbers.  Can you show the code that prints this out -- perhaps this is an issue.  A RSSI value of 0 indicates that the beacon was not detected in the past second.  If the 0 values in the logs indicate a raw RSSI field value of zero, then that suggests the beacon was not detected for many ranging cycles in the background on iOS.  This is **not** normal behavior, so I suspect some other factor besides the app being in the background is the root cause.

Comment: You might try repeating the test with the exact same conditions (holding the phone in the same way) for both foreground and background.

Comment: Hi davidgyoung. I just call the CLBeacon beacon.rssi: - (void)sendNotification:(CLBeacon*) beacon
{
    // Create the REST call string.
    NSString *restCallString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://1.1.1.1/api/v1/ranging?uuid=%@&major=%@&minor=%@&rssi=%lu", [beacon.proximityUUID UUIDString], beacon.major, beacon.minor, beacon.rssi];

Comment: I tried to carry the smart phone in my hands; and the results go better. However, today I had overall much more valuable RSSI values. Maybe it was an interference problem.